# How to use org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender in log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

Below is the sample used in log4j 1.x. I am not getting any example to convert the same in log4j2.

```
<appender name="CoalescingStatisticsAppender"
    class="org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
    <!--
        The TimeSlice option is used to determine the time window for which
        all received StopWatch logs are aggregated to create a single
        GroupedTimingStatistics log. Here we set it to 10 seconds, overriding
        the default of 30000 ms
    -->
    <param name="TimeSlice" value="30000" />
    <appender-ref ref="perf4jFileAppender" />
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Appender won't work as is in Log4j 2. It would have to be rewritten.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I write it?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to know that Log4j 2 supports nanoTime timestamps in PatternLayout. This, in combination with the low overhead Async Loggers, allow you to use Log4j as a rough profiling tool.

Comment: That was also one thing but the main query was about how to use the same appender as is in log4j2.xml. If I understood correctly by looking lo4j2 documentation, I need to create one Plugin for it. All the examples given are extending one appender. In my case, I guess it would be AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender but that definitely is not going to support constructor. Please elaborate.